# How to make multiple changes in a table at once in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, command, where-clause

I have a table `index` which contains columns like `accountno, opendate, name, address,` etc.

I want to change the open date of some account numbers to a specific value.

How can I do this at once?

Meaning, I have to put the opendate of some account numbers (more than 100) to 01.01.1990.

But the account numbers are different. How can I do this in a single query?

Comment: The question is answered correctly below.  But before implementing, could I suggest you choose a name other than "index" for your table?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
UPDATE 
  MyIndexTable 
SET 
  opendate = <desired date> 
WHERE 
  accountno IN (
    a1, a2, ..., a100
  );
```

If your account numbers don't satisfy a closed formula, you have to write out all 100 of them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a comma separated list, or a table with the IDs of the records you would like to change (this only works if you are setting them all to the same value) Here is an example with a Comma seperated list:

```
 Update index 
   SET opendate = '1/1/1900'
 WHERE accountno IN (123, 456)
```

You can also load the IDs into a table then the query would be

```
 update index
   set opendate = '1/1/1900'
 WHERE accountno IN (SELECT accountno from acctnos_table)
```

Again this only works if you are setting all the records to the same date.